# Select all checkbox in primefaces

Tags: javascript, checkbox, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox, selectbooleancheckbox

The requirement of the logic is:
- I have a list of checkbox (I use p:selectManyCheckbox).
- I also have a checkbox which if it is checked, other check box should be checked also (I use p:selectBooleanCheckbox for this)
- Let me give an specific example, now I have 3 checkboxes:
+ Select all
+ Item 1
+ Item 2

If 'select all' is checked, 'item 1' and 'item 2' are checked. If 'select all' is unchecked, 'item 1' and 'item 2' are unchecked.
If one of 'item 1' or 'item 2' is unchecked, 'select all' should be unchecked. If both 'item 1' and 'item 2' are checked, 'select all' should be checked automatically.

To implement that, I use javascript for onchange event of every checkbox.
For select all, onchange = updateOtherCheckboxes(otherCheckboxes, selectAllCheckbox)

```js
function updateCheckboxes(otherCheckboxes, selectAllCheckbox) {
 otherCheckboxes.inputs.each(function() {
  if (selectAllCheckbox.isChecked()) {
   $(this).prop('checked', false);
  } else {
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
  $(this).trigger('click');
 });
}
```

For other checkboxes, onchange = updateSelectAllCheckbox(otherCheckboxes, selectAllCheckbox)

```js
function updateSelectAllCheckbox(otherCheckboxes, selectAllCheckbox) {
 var notAllCheckboxesChecked = false;
 otherCheckboxes.inputs.each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked') == false) {
   notAllCheckboxesChecked = true;
   return false;
  }
 });
 if (notAllCheckboxesChecked && selectAllCheckbox.input.is(':checked') == true) {
  selectAllCheckbox.input.trigger('click');
 } else if (!notAllCheckboxesChecked && selectAllCheckbox.input.is(':checked') == false) {
  selectAllCheckbox.input.trigger('click');
 }
}
```

**The problem here is that**, in updateCheckboxes() function, other checkboxes's click event are triggered and updateSelectAllCheckbox will be called, but I don't want that. So how can I prevent updateSelectAllCheckbox() function to be invoked in updateCheckboxes() function after I trigger the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `$(this).trigger('check')` because this will fire the click event, your earlier code `$(this).prop('checked', true)` already makes sure the checkbox will be checked so you don't have to fire the `click` event anymore.

If the `$(this).prop('checked', true)` does not work you could also try: `$(this).attr('checked', true);`

Comment: Hi Sven, I tried it without trigger('click') but other checkboxes were not checked/unchecked on UI

Comment: @nguyenbkcse i updated my answer with another suggestion :)

Comment: Hi Sven, I tried also your new solution but it stays the same :(

Comment: Could you provide a live working example in your answer or a link to codepen with the working code? So i can try a few things :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't now where to provide you my live code because I'm using primefaces and seems that there's no online place for testing primefaces code.

Comment: Do you have the HTML and CSS you use for this :) if you could add these in your answer that would be sufficient @nguyenbkcse

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to do that, because in JS function, I used widget of primefaces, but if it's easy, I will provide you :)

Comment: If you could provide that I will try to get it to work, worth a shot :) @nguyenbkcse